# Password protect IIS server

Tags: security, authentication, iis

Looking for a way to password protect an application in IIS.

- Windows auth is not an option
- Helicon Ape is not an option

Searching online, can't see any simple way to do this through configuration.

Happy to look at off the shelf solutions also however haven't seen any decent options apart from Helicon Ape which isn't an option in this case.

Comment: Auth is kinda a big realm. Can you offer a lot more details about what it is you are trying to do?  My initial reaction is to suggest BASIC or OAUTH, but it really depends.

Comment: Trying to lock it down at server rather than application level. Both basic and oauth are application based authentication. Ideally I'd like something protecting it at IIS layer before it reaches application.

Comment: What you are trying sounds good in theory, but logically there is no difference. The request is still going to get authenticated before any content is served.

Comment: Sorry but I would disagree with you there. When the authentication is happening at the server level, this allows me to apply it to N+1 applications across that server. If I'm doing it at the application level, I have to setup and configure for each application requiring authentication - not ideal! Thank you though

Comment: Check out ISAPI filters, I haven't used them for auth because I do it at the app level, but seems like a very reasonable use. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524610(v=vs.90).aspx